# How to set foreign key constraint on owned property table from another table in EF Core 7

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am adding internationalization feature in relational database. I have `Languages` table where I define all supported languages:

```
public class Language
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Two letter language ISO code
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; set; } // Primary Key
    
    // Other properties...
}
```

I have `LocalizedString` class that represents text in one of the defined language

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents culture specific text
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Language">RFC 4646 Standard identification for a language</param>
/// <param name="Text">Text in specified culture</param>
public sealed record LocalizedString(string Language, string Text);
```

I use `LocalizedString` for properties that should be defined in supported languages

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public LocalizedString Name { get; set; } // Owned type
    public LocalizedString Description { get; set; } // Owned type

    // Other properties...
}

public class AnotherEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public LocalizedString Title { get; set; } // Owned type

    // Other properties...
}
```

My database configurations look like this:

```
public class SomeEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SomeEntity>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SomeEntity> entity)
  {
    entity.ToTable("SomeEntities");

    // Other configurations...

    entity.OwnsMany(x => x.Name, p =>
    {
      p.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("SomeEntityId");
      p.Property(t => t.Language).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(5);
      p.Property(t => t.Text).IsRequired();
    });

    entity.OwnsMany(x => x.Description, p =>
    {
      p.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("SomeEntityId");
      p.Property(t => t.Language).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(5);
      p.Property(t => t.Text).IsRequired();
    });
  }
}

public class AnotherEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AnotherEntity>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SomeEntity> entity)
  {
    entity.ToTable("AnotherEntities");

    // Other configurations...

    entity.OwnsMany(x => x.Title, p =>
    {
      p.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("AnotherEntityId");
      p.Property(t => t.Language).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(5);
      p.Property(t => t.Text).IsRequired();
    });
  }
}
```

Now I want to add foreign key constraint on `Language` column in owned tables that will reference to the `Id` the `Languages` table.

I've tried to add another `WithOwner` config.

```
entity.OwnsMany(x => x.Title, p =>
{
    p.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("AnotherEntityId");
    p.WithOwner("Languages").HasForeignKey("Language"); // Added this line
    p.Property(t => t.Language).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(5);
    p.Property(t => t.Text).IsRequired();
});
```

But it did not work.

Is there any way to achieve this without adding additional navigation properties or polluting my models?

I'm using .NET 7, Entity Framework Core 7 and a Postresql database driver.